# R Markdown Error in `lmerTest::as_lmerModLmerTest()`

Tags: r-markdown, markdown, lme4

I am running a moderation analysis for a lmer model and I get the following error only when I knit the document (not when I run the code directly in the console):

```
s_moderation<-lmer(social~gndr+age.decades+migrant*(f1.selftranscendence+f2.openness+f3.selfenhancement+f4.conservationism)+(1|cntry), ess, control = lmerControl(optimizer ='optimx', optCtrl=list(method='nlminb')), weights=pspwght)

s_slopef1<-sim_slopes(s_moderation, pred='f1.selftranscendence', modx='migrant', digits=3)
s_slopef2<-sim_slopes(s_moderation, pred='f2.openness', modx='migrant', digits=3)
s_slopef3<-sim_slopes(s_moderation, pred='f3.selfenhancement', modx='migrant', digits=3)
s_slopef4<-sim_slopes(s_moderation, pred='f4.conservationism', modx='migrant', digits=3)

Quitting from lines 208-212 [5] (Results.Rmd)
Error in `lmerTest::as_lmerModLmerTest()`:
! Unable to extract deviance function from model fit
Backtrace:
 1. interactions::sim_slopes(...)
 3. jtools:::summ.merMod(...)
 4. jtools:::get_all_sat(model)
 5. lmerTest::as_lmerModLmerTest(model)
```

As I mentioned, the code works fine when I run it in the console, but always gives me that error when kniting. I tried specifying lme4::lmer and adding RMEL=FALSE in the model, but nothing solves the problem